# IOS app to upload data to database using php

Tags: php, ios, sql, objective-c, arrays

Im creating an app where the user inputs match events in a rugby game and the player who done it. e.g. pass,wing or try,scrumhalf. This information needs to be uploaded to an external database for the website to have access to it.

I don't want every time the user clicks an event for it to upload it to the database. I want them to do a whole match with it somehow storing it on the ipad. The user then clicks an upload button and all the events get uploaded to php which then inserts them into the database.

How is the best way to go about this?
I've tried everything and not sure.
Suggestions and example code would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your app should /may do a 'simple' call to a [REST-API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

You should find a lot of examples for that. For networking you should find a more comfortable lib at cocoapods.